# How to Re-Invite Someone to a Google Group?

Tags: google-groups

Is there a way to re-invite someone to a Google Group?  As the owner of the group, I used the invitation feature to send an invite to a friend of mine.  He claims he never received the email (checked his spam folder, etc.).  So I'd like to re-send it.  However, Google Groups tells me that "no invitations were sent" because that email address was already invited.

I also tried to add that email address directly, but that feature seems to be entirely broken.  I can enter the information, but there's no button on the page to actually submit the form and add the user.

Does anybody have any idea how I can get around this?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that they've tweaked the interface again and this should now be possible.

1. Go to the "Manage" section
2. Under "Members" (left-side menu) should be an option for "Outstanding invites". Click that.
3. Now you should have a list of people who have been sent an invitation but who have not joined. Check the box next to all of the people you want to re-invite.
4. Click the "Resend Invitation" button which now appears at the top.

Answer (score 0):

If your friend is using Gmail, you could invite him by adding a `+something` to his username, e.g. instead of `myfriend@gmail.com`, try inviting `myfriend+foobar@gmail.com`.

[Gmail ignores everything after the `+` when delivering the message.](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=12096)

Comment: Except that makes it the email address registered to the group and complicates things when trying to send messages to the group via email or unsubscribe.

Answer (score -1):

This does not seem to be possible with new google groups.

If you go to the home google groups page, you can switch back to the old version.
Then, you can go to manage members and the following applies:
http://support.google.com/groups/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75247

- Select the member
- Choose unsubscribe
- Resend the invitation